# How to import java class in python

Tags: java, python, class, import, jython

I have a class (named `properties.class`), and I have to import in Python (see code below).

```
import properties
```

however I am receiving the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\hooks.py", line 361, in <module>
    import properties
ImportError: No module named properties
```

Comment: Python or Jython ? You won't go anywhere with a "normal" python.

Comment: Hi. You may well need to use the python package known as javaclass: [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/javaclass]. I trust you have done this?

Comment: Wait your class is named `properties`? What is the package?

Comment: how will i know if it is a python or jython ?

Comment: my class name is properties and my files python file is hooks.py

Comment: How do you start python?

Comment: i have my hooks.py files and just edit with IDLE (python 2.7)

Comment: Python runs Java bytecode?